# Black screen apperas in graph created with cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am using cytoscape.js version 2.0.3 for creating graph. I have noticed a problem that sometimes entire canvas drawn by cytoscape.js becomes black and after few seconds, it recovers. This problem occurs when some event (e.g., 'tap', 'cxttap') occurs, especially for large graph. What should I do to avoid it? Please help.

Comment: jQuery v1.8.3 is used.

Comment: What browsers and OSes are affected?  Have you tried an updated version of the library?  You should post an example that generates the bug to JS Bin or similar.

Comment: Firefox v27.0 on Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit OS

Comment: You should post an example that generates the issue you describe on v2.1.0.